# Syncing a local bare lfs repository with its remote

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

Our project has a very large git lfs repository which is stored on a remote server(Bitbucket).
To avoid repeatedly redownloading it for each work context, I've setup the following:

Remote git lfs repository -> local bare lfs repository -> local cloned lfs repository

Problem is that after the initial creation of the local bare lfs repository, any attempts to pull/fetch from the remote git lfs repository doesn't have the expected side effect.
I.E. Commits made to the remote git lfs repository are not pulled/fetched into the local bare lfs repository after its initial creation.

Local bare lfs repository is created using:

```
git clone --bare <remote_git_url>
git fetch --all
git lfs fetch --all
```

Local bare lfs repository is updated using:

```
git fetch --all
git lfs fetch --all
```

Problem is that the update doesn't work as intended.
I.E. commits made to the remote git lfs repository are not pulled/fetched as intended into the local bare lfs repository.

Any help/insight would be appreciated.